# As3 textarea limit

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I made a simple chat application but i have this problem the text area will fill up and the users will have to then clear it.. How can i make it so if the text area reaches a certain amount of characters it will clear the old chat text ?

```
public function receiveMsg(userName:String,type:String,msg:String,txtColor:String):void{
            if(type == "user"){
                ConsoleTxt.htmlText += "<b>"+userName+"</b>: <font color='"+txtColor+"'>"+msg+"</font> \n"

            }

            if(type == "server"){
                ConsoleTxt.htmlText += "<b><font color='#6ade57'>SERVER</font></b> "+userName+" "+msg+"\n"
            }

            if(type == "disconnect"){
                ConsoleTxt.htmlText += "<b><font color='#6ade57'>SERVER</font></b> "+userName+" <font color='#fc0000'>"+msg+"</font>\n"

            }

            ConsoleTxt.verticalScrollPosition = ConsoleTxt.maxVerticalScrollPosition
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should work on number of lines & not on characters in the textarea.

Something like :

```
textarea.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

var maxLines = 5;

function changeHandler(event:Event):void {  

    if(textarea.numLines > maxLines)

      textarea.text = textarea.text.substring(textarea.getLineLength(0));
}
```

should ensure that there are always max 5 lines in the textarea, else the oldest line gets deleted.

Comment: thanks for this but for some reason my textarea dos not have the property .numLines any idea why? im using flex is that helps

Comment: Probably because it isn't a TLFTextField

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem fixed the issue with setting all data into an array collection.

```
private var chatHolder:Array = new Array();

        public function receiveMsg(userName:String,type:String,msg:String,txtColor:String):void{
            for(var i:int = 0;i < chatHolder.length;i ++){

                if(i > 4){
                    chatHolder.shift();
                }
            }

            if(type == "user"){     
                chatHolder.push("<b><a href='event:"+userName+"'>"+userName+"</a></b>: <font color='"+txtColor+"'>"+msg+"</font> \n")
            }
}
```